# GotFocus event of TextBox in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Calibrun Micro and WPF, I have a textBox and when i recieves a focus I want to call a method in ViewModel and same when it leaves LostFocus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Message.Attach syntax](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/07/17/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-pt-3-all-about-actions.aspx) to hook on the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event

The following code will call the `GotFocusMethod` and `LostFocusMethod` on your viewmodel:

```
<TextBox cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action GotFocusMethod]; 
                 [Event LostFocus] = [Action LostFocusMethod]" />
```

Note: don't forget the separating the actions with a semicolon `;` when you declare multiple actions.